# How to Return the text and CRLFs between 2 Date Strings with VBA and RegExp

Tags: regex, vba, ms-word

I have a Word macro whose purpose is to return the content in a Word file between the first two date strings starting a line.

For example, assume the following text in a Word document:

```
5/1/2023
blah
blah
blah

4/1/2023
jabber
jabber
jabber
```

The Word macro is supposed to return:

```
blah
blah
blah
```

However, it instead returns:

```
blahblahblah
```

The CRLFs are removed which is not desired.

Here is my Word VBA code which I run on the active document:

```
Function getLastNote()
'extracts content between two date strings. The result should be the latest note entry
Dim regEx As Object, matchCollection As Object, extractedString As String

Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

With regEx
  .IgnoreCase = True
  .Global = False    ' Only look for 1 match; False is actually the default.
  .Pattern = "\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}((.|\n)*?)\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d\d\d\d"
End With

Set matchCollection = regEx.Execute(ActiveDocument.Content.text)
If matchCollection.Count > 0 Then
    ' Extract the first submatch's (capture group's) value -
    getLastNote = matchCollection(0).submatches(0)
Else
    getLastNote = ActiveDocument.Content 'there's no match so return the text of the doc.
End If
End Function
```

How can I retain the CRLFs? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is just the way newlines are encoded in the text. I
would have thought that it would be Windows newlines such as `\r\n` so
I used `\r?\n` in the pattern to be Linux/Windows compatible. But it
seems that `ActiveDocument.Content.Text` only contains `\r`, which is
rather surprising!

But anyway, we can just replace `.*?` by `[\s\S]*?` in order to match
anything including newlines. This is because the VBA regexp engine
doesn't have the `s` modifier to make `.` also match newlines.

I also changed your pattern to match the next date **or the end of the
document**, in case you only have a single note.

I also captured the date in a group, so that we can return an object
with both the date and the text values.

### VBA Code

#### The *clsNote* class

Create a new class module named *clsNote* with the instancing option set
to `2 - PublicNotCreatable` so that your function can create an instance
of it.

The code of the class is simple, but could be improved in the future:

```vb
Option Explicit

Public strDate As String 'It would be better with a DateTime object.
Public strText As String

Public Sub DisplayMsgBox()
    MsgBox strText, vbInformation, strDate
End Sub
```

#### Your function to get the latest note

```vb
'Add ref to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" in Tools -> References.

Option Explicit

Function getLastNote() As clsNote
'Returns the last note from the current document.
'The result should be the latest note entry, at the top of the document.

    Dim regEx As RegExp, matchCollection As Object, oNote As clsNote
    Set regEx = New RegExp
    Set oNote = New clsNote
    
    With regEx
      .IgnoreCase = True
      .MultiLine = False
      'Only look for 1 match; False is actually the default.
      .Global = False
      'First group is the date and second group is the content between the next date or document end.
      .Pattern = "(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4})[\r\n]+([\s\S]*?)[\r\n]+(?:\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}|$)"
    End With
    
    Set matchCollection = regEx.Execute(ActiveDocument.Content.Text)
    
    If matchCollection.Count > 0 Then
        'Submatches:
        '- index 0: date.
        '- index 1: text.
        oNote.strDate = matchCollection(0).submatches(0)
        oNote.strText = matchCollection(0).submatches(1)
    Else
        'There's no match so return the text of the doc.
        oNote.strDate = ""
        oNote.strText = ActiveDocument.Content.Text
    End If
    
    Set getLastNote = oNote

End Function
```

#### A test in the execution console

Assuming the `getLastNote()` function is on `ThisDocument`, just run:

```
ThisDocument.getLastNote.DisplayMsgBox
```

[image: message box]